Fisher's exact tests and the Bonferroni correction?
I am applying Fisher's exact tests to my data as my data sample is small, my data is very similar to this one(which I found through Reddit).




N1  = Man
N2 = Woman




Menu 1
1
6


Menu 2
2
9


Menu 3
2
4


Menu 4
4
3


Menu 5
4
3


Menu 6
3
3


Total
16
28



However, apart from using Fisher's exact test to test if gender has a relationship with how the menus are chosen, I also want to test several hypotheses, for example, the number of Women who chose Menu 1 is significantly different compared to Men, the number of Women who chose Menu 2 significantly differs to Man, etc, what kind of tests I shall do?
To my understanding, I need to create six separate contingency tables like the one below to conduct Fisher's exact test for each hypothesis.




N2  = Man
N2 = Woman




Menu 1 selected
1
6


Menu 1 not selected
15
22



I'd like to ask is this approach correct? Also I want to know if I do so, do I need to apply the Bonferroni correction?
Thank you for your answers!

Does each person choose only one menu? Or can they choose multiple menus?

Hi, They can choose multiple menus

If you reformat it by person with seven variables: their sex (0/1) and for each menu a 0/1 variable for whether they chose it you can then do a logistic regression to see if menu predicts sex (well strictly speaking retrodicts it). Would that answer your question?

You say that a given person can choose multiple menus. Then, in your grand totals, there is some double counting (the same person is counted more than once), and Fisher (or $\chi^2$ for that matter), are not appropriate tests (the multiple categories need to be mutually exclusive!).  2x6, or 2x2 contingency tables are not the right tool...

@mdewey Hi, thank you for your answers! I tried the logistic regression, but it seems my sample size is still not very efficient to converge Do you know what approach I shall use if I want to demonstrate for individual rows, for example, Men Choose Menu 2 significantly greater than Women?

@jginestet Thank you for pointing it out! Do you know what a proper tool is? I am not really new to statistical analysis...

No, no obvious solution comes to mind. Would need to know much more about the details (what really are these "menus"? How/why can a subject choose more than 1? Are the choices done in 1 "visit", or repeated "visits"? Etc...

@jginestet Hi, The detail is that we collected open-ended answers under the same question from each participant under 2 conditions( you can consider as C1/C2 or man/woman), and I summarized common themes from the question content and compared the distribution of themes between 2 conditions.
For example, for question 1, I summarized theme A and theme B from the C1 participant's answer; and summarized theme B from C2's answer, then the count for theme A and B for C1 plus 1, theme B for C2 plus 1, etc.
